# трабл с маршрутизацией react

Tags: reactjs

Всем ку! Такая задача у меня: существует образовательный портал для студентов; на нем есть 4 ссылки, каждая из которых ведёт на страницу с предметами 1го,2го,3го или 4го курса соответственно; переходя на страницу с предметами, делается запрос к json, откуда и берем данные о предметах того или иного курса; следовательно на странице с предметами размещены ссылки на подробное описание того или иного предмета, и вот вопрос: как в таком случае создавать руты на страницы с описанием предмета??? Я только начинаю изучать реакт, поэтому не знаю, что делать =((

Comment: Также как ты создашь роуты на страницы 1го 2го 3го также и на предметы, какая разница на чо создавать? механизм один и тот же как я понимаю. Куча примеров в инете https://reactdev.ru/libs/react-router/

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение!
Короче, для страниц с описанием предмета я создал вот такой рут

```
<Route path="/:id" element={<SubjectPage /> } /> // это написано в файле со всеми рутами
```

А потом в файле SubjectPage я написал следующее:

```
const params = useParams();
```

И теперь из объекта params я могу получить значение id из адресной строки

```
params.id
```

Как-то так =))